# How to post form using curl in php and redirect to form action?

Tags: php, curl

How do I post this form:

```
<form action ="http://google.com" id="checkpayment" style="display:none" method="post">
        <input value="crm_pg1" name="uid">
        <input value="98" name="passcode">
        <input value="10" name="payamnt">
        <input value="150001451" name="session">
        <input value="demo@gmail.com" name="emailid">
        <input value="9865321478" name="mobileno">
        <input value="normal" name="paytype">
        <input value="home" name="segment">
        <input value="FTTH" name="sub_segment">
        <input value="http://example.com" name="returnurl">
        <INPUT TYPE ="SUBMIT">
        </form>
```

and I am using this php code:

```
$curl_connection =
          curl_init('http://google.com');

        //set options
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
          "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        //set data to be posted
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

        //perform our request
        $result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
        //show information regarding the request
         print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
        echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' .
                        curl_error($curl_connection);

        //close the connection
        curl_close($curl_connection);
```

I don't know if it's working or not, but how do I post a form and redirect to form action?

For example if I posted this form using curl from my site i.e; example.com and after successful submit its redirect to google.com.

Answer (score 0):

First your action should be the php file you want to post the data from the form to.
Second you can get the data from the form with $_POST in the .php file
Third, after you make the call to api with curl you can redirect with 
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

Comment: So to understand, you want to post data from the form to curl to make a call and redirect back?

Comment: when i post a data using curl its redirect to form action